# Umbraco - Media - Image not found

Tags: content-management-system, png, umbraco

I've uploaded a couple PNG images to Umbraco via the Media section that I want to be able to show in a page but for some reason it cannot find the image, even when I go to Media and click on the thumbnail and it opens a new tab, it gives me a 404 error. However this works for JPG images that I've uploaded in the Media section.

Other PNGs that I have, such as the ones in the images folder for the CSS, loads fine so it seems like it's just the images I'm uploading via the Media section.

Is there a config setting I'm missing somewhere?

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using? Has the configuration been tweaked at all or is this a clean install?

Comment: It's version 6.2.1 and it's a clean install, no configuration has been tweaked.

Comment: Assuming that you haven't installed any packages that may affect this, and if it's a clean install, if PNG files aren't rendering in the media library raise it as a bug with Umbraco.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Maybe [Webmasters SE](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) is a better fit.

Comment: I agree, this really should be asked at http://our.umbraco.org/ or raised as a bug with Umbraco.

Comment: I didn't get any replies to another question I asked on there so thought I would give it a try on here. The question can be closed now as I've resolved the problem. There was another rewrite rule in a config file from the templates that was removing part of the URL for PNGs which is why it was not finding the file.